# Make: command not found when specifying cross compiler path

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a kernel on my FOX G20 V board. In order to do so, I have to specify the cross compiler in one of the steps `arm-linux-gnueabi`. The command is

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- at91-ariag25.dtb

So in order for the compiler to know where the executable of the cross compiler is, I specify it in the path by doing

> export PATH=$PATH:/home/path_goes_here/bin

When I do `echo $PATH`, I get the right path of the cross compiler. However, now when I do the make of my project, I receive:

> make: command not found

But when I don't specify the path of the compiler, the make works but when it reaches the point of the cross compiler, it gives me:

> make: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

I think that my make is not in my system path when I change it to the cross compiler. Therefore, how can I add both the make and the cross compiler to the system path?

**EDIT**

My cross compiler is actually `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7`, and not `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. Yet when I specify the cross compiler in the `make` by doing `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`, I get:

> make: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

Because `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` isn't the one it should be looking for. Yet when I specify `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7`, it appends `gcc` at the end of that and gives me:

> make: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7gcc: Command not found

**EDIT 2**

I simply renamed the cross compiler and that seemed to work. But now, I get the error:

> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: > I get the right path of the cross compile - write this path here.

Comment: Do you have make command installed?

Comment: can you write the result of `readelf -a /path/to/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc | grep "Requesting"` here?. you might have to move the whole path to right position if the programi interpreter does not exist in that path.

Comment: I do have make installed (since I've used it before). I've tried appending the cross compiler path to the existing path: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/dico/gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi_4.7.2-1/usr/bin`, but when I try to compile, I still get `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found`.

Comment: @ymonad I get `Error: :/home/dico/gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi_4.7.2-1/usr/bin is not an ordinary file`.

Comment: @JohnSmith You should run `readelf -a /home/dico/gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi_4.7.2-1/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc | grep "Requesting"`

Comment: @LeeDuhem I get `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]`.

Comment: @JohnSmith And `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` exists in your system?

Comment: @LeeDuhem and the rest, please check edit.

Comment: @JohnSmith Well, you could create a symbolic link named `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` to your actual cross-compiler `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7`. Other symbolic links to other tools, such as `ld`, `as`, may also need.

Comment: @LeeDuhem What do you mean create a symbolic link? Can I simply rename the cross compiler?

Comment: Please check the edit once more.

Comment: @JohnSmith You can, but symbolic link is safer.

Comment: @LeeDuhem, can you check my edit? I'm getting a `cc1` error.

Comment: @JohnSmith It looks like your cross-toolchain does not function. Where is that `cc1` in your system? Do you have an `arm-linux-gnueabi-cc1` or something like that?

Comment: @LeeDuhem I've checked and it in fact doesn't exist in the cross compiler path. Do you know where I can download an `arm-linux-gnueabi` package manually (since the machine I'm working on doesn't have internet - not this one)? Because the one I've downloaded doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @JohnSmith I do not know that :-(

Comment: Ok. I have another cross compiler that I will try. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `cc1` doesn't have to be in `$PATH`.  On my stock x86_64 Debian, I do have `gcc` and `g++` (compiler drivers) in my `$PATH` but `cc1` and `cc1plus` (actual compilers) are in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6` which only the compiler drivers are aware of.

Comment: Never rename files installed by Debian packages! Rename it back to what it was! You were on the right track: what you need to do is add the right directory to your `$PATH`. You can also set `PATH` inside your Makefile, using the export statement (assuming GNU make).

Comment: @reinierpost Thanks for the clairification. However, as I mentioned, the compilation seems to look for a cross compiler of a certain name, and I'm not really sure how to change that. So instead, I changed the name as I was told was okay to do.

Comment: It would be better to figure out the logic by which it appends `-gcc` and see if you can change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the binaries in your toolchain, you should create symbolic links that obey the naming convention required by your Makefile. The links should point to the respective binary that uses the non-conformant naming scheme.

```
cd /home/dico/gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi_4.7.2-1/usr/bin
ln -s arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `CROSS_COMPILE` is only a shorthand for setting all of `CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)cc` `AS=$(CROSS_COMPILE)as` `LD=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld` etc etc (just take a look at the top level `Makefile` with `less(1)`)

So you should be able to do this

```
$ export ARCH=arm
$ xc=arm-linux-gnueabi-
$ export CC=$(xc)gcc-4.7
$ export AS=$(xc)as-4.7
$ export LD=$(xc)ld-4.7
etc etc
$ make at91-ariag25.dtb
```